# Is there a way to ensure SQL Server identity column values are always consistent in an order even after many server restarts?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I have been having challenge with identity columns jumping after some server restart, an example is it would start counting from say 1,2,3,4 then later it jumps to 108,109,110 then later jumps to 10001, 10002, 10003.

I am now currently managing the IDs manually through triggers but this is an expensive exercise overtime.

Comment: identity values should be treated as *opaque* values that happen to fit in a numeric column. If you *care* about the numerical value, you're probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: Why does it matter which values your autogenerated ids have? You will get gaps anyway in the moment you delete a record ...

Comment: Note, as well, that skipping tends to happen more often happen if the Instance (or host) isn't shut down properly. If you're restarting the host, and it's skipping, that sounds like the service isn't shutting properly.

Comment: Also, @MikePoole, it's not a "bug", it's by design. A bug would mean it's happening in error; that isn't the case. The flag `-T272` doesn't fix a "bug", it changes the behaviour for a less performant one that doesn't use a cache.

Comment: @MikePoole that's a *very* bad idea. There's no bug, except in the application that assumes IDENTITY values are strictly incremental. Databases that behave the way you assume like MySQL can easily freeze in high traffic. In a high traffic system getting strictly incremental values would require locking *across all CPU cores*. This may not sound bad if you have just a quad-core laptop, but on a 64-core server (which isn't that big for a DB server), that's a 64-way lock which can result in **significant delays** or even deadlocks.

Comment: In a recent case a MySQL database server would freeze on a multi-CPU, many-core machine because the database couldn't handle the synchronization latency between *CPUs*. Using a single huge CPU was OK, but having the same number of cores over 4 CPUs resulted in a freeze. Precalculating and caching IDENTITY ranges reduces the need for locks significantly, not only because there's less need for syncing, but the sync requests are spread apart.

Answer (score 1):

An option to avoid the Identity Cache on a table level is to use sequence (with `no cache`) instead of identity.

```
create sequence dbo.YourTableId as int minvalue 1 start with 1 increment by 1 no cache;
GO

create table dbo.YourTable
(
    Id int not null constraint DF_YourTable_Id default (next value for dbo.YourTableId),
    [Name] varchar(50) not null,
    ...
```

[CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SQL/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Warning**: setting the sequence to `no cache` may impact the insertion performance.

To find a compromise you can set the cache size to a smaller number than the default value. For example, use `cache 10` instead of `no cache`.

[Here is more.](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-to-avoid-an-identity-jump-issue-identity_cache-with-the-help-of-trace-command-t272/)